# Can I install 2 or more Android SDK when using Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, versions

I am new to android developments. I am setting up my android development environment using Eclipse. I have a test smart phone with Android version 4.2.2. The automatic installation installed the latest Android SDK version, which is 5.1.1. My questions are:
1. Do I have to install the SDK version 4.2.2 to test on my test mobile with Android 4.2.2.?
2. What will happened if I do not install SDK version 4.2.2 and try to run app developed with SDK version 5.1.1?
3. If I have 3 or more Android units, each with different Android version, then do I have to install all the matching SDK versions?

Thank you for your help.
regards,
John

Comment: Welcome to SO, The minSdk that is specified when you create an application is the lowest version your app will support, your target sdk is the highest android version , you can test any version that falls in-between these two version. However if you are using a emulator , you cant run a emulator of a specific version without downloading the said version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem if you use the latest SDK version ; actually, this is recommended.

However, make sure to set the correct "Target SDK", i.e. the highest android version you have successfully tested your app with, and the "Minimum Required SDK" as well.